# New Nexus 5X can't find my home wifi

Tags: wi-fi, nexus-5x

I just booted up my new Nexus 5X and I immediately ran into a problem. The phone simply refuses to find my home WiFi network. It works perfectly fine on my old Nexus 5, on my Mac, on my kindle and so on.

I have a Sky Hub router, default settings. I simply don't know what to do. It finds a lot of other networks, just not mine. How can I solve this? And to make clear, it's not that I can't connect to the network, it's not even on the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what version of the Nexus 5X you have it might not have the same WiFi bands as your router. I'd force your router to band 11 just to test it out. Your router also might be set to a security standard your phone can't recognize.

Comment: I changed my router channel from 12 to 11 and now it found the network. Weird. Thanks!

Comment: Had similar problem today - Nexus 5X refused to see the 3G WiFi router from time to time. Checked, the channel seiection was set to  `auto` on router, hard-forcing it to `11` fixed the problem.

Comment: I don't have access into router WiFi settings, is there any way to fix this on the phone side?

Answer (score 1):

There exists a regulation about WLAN channels

```
https://www.hypercable.fr/images/stories/wirake/24_35__5.4_GHZ_international_rules.pdf
```

According to it not all channels are allowed in all countries. Apparently, Nexus5x is having some default setup where some channels aren't visible (it may depends on where the phone was manufactured), so in my case it wasn't able to detect my Wi-Fi on channel 13.

However, Nexus5x can detect the country code from SIM card. Therefore, if you are in a country where the channel on which your Wi-Fi runs is allowed (not sure if you'd be able to successfully setup WLAN on channel that is disabled by regulation in your country), try put SIM card in your phone. Then it should find your Wi-Fi and show it in available connections.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've borrowed a sim card to connect to the hotel wifi and now it works.